# How to introduce a new header to a CSV file based on condition using gawk

Tags: csv, gawk, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a csv file from I wish to extract only column number *7* and *11*. Depending on the value of column 7 which has either value `OK` or `KO` I wish to insert a column next to it called `value` where the mapping is:

```
OK -> 0
KO -> 1
```

and additionally, I add a simple String column at the very beginning.

My `.awk` file is as follows:

```c
BEGIN {FS=";";OFS=","}
{
    value=0
    if($7=="KO") {
        value=1
    }
    print "Measure_QS",$7,value,$11 
}
```

Using the file:

```bsh
gawk -f converter.awk Dataset.csv | head -n 10
```

provides the following:

```
Measure_QS,result,0,time_stamp
Measure_QS,OK,0,2020-01-17 11:53:33.000
Measure_QS,OK,0,2020-01-17 11:53:22.000
Measure_QS,OK,0,2020-01-17 11:51:42.000
Measure_QS,OK,0,2020-01-17 11:51:30.000
Measure_QS,OK,0,2020-01-17 11:51:06.000
Measure_QS,OK,0,2020-01-17 11:50:53.000
Measure_QS,OK,0,2020-01-17 11:50:41.000
Measure_QS,OK,0,2020-01-17 11:50:29.000
Measure_QS,OK,0,2020-01-17 11:50:17.000
```

The headers are `Measure_QS,result,0,time_stamp`. I wish to have the following header: `Measure_QS,result,value,time_stamp`

where am I going wrong here?

Comment: Can you add the first few lines of Dataset,csv as well in the question?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to tackle this problem using `NR` variable in `gawk`

```c
BEGIN {FS=";";OFS=",";print "measurement","result","value","time_stamp"}
{
    value=0
    if(NR!=1) {
        if($7=="KO") {
            value=1
        }
        print "Measure_QS",$7,value,$11
    }
}
```

and this was able to work well with

```bsh
gawk -f converter.awk Dataset.csv | head -n 10
```

```
measurement,result,value,time_stamp
Measure_QS,OK,0,2020-01-17 11:53:33.000
Measure_QS,OK,0,2020-01-17 11:53:22.000
Measure_QS,OK,0,2020-01-17 11:51:42.000
Measure_QS,OK,0,2020-01-17 11:51:30.000
Measure_QS,OK,0,2020-01-17 11:51:06.000
Measure_QS,OK,0,2020-01-17 11:50:53.000
Measure_QS,OK,0,2020-01-17 11:50:41.000
Measure_QS,OK,0,2020-01-17 11:50:29.000
Measure_QS,OK,0,2020-01-17 11:50:17.000
```

Comment: if you do [what @Icarus suggested](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/606276/how-to-introduce-a-new-header-to-a-csv-file-based-on-condition-using-gawk#comment1131647_606276) then we could show you a more concise, more robust way of doing that.